# Listbox2 to display sheets of selected workbooks only from Listbox1

Tags: vba, excel

There are 2 Listboxes - Listbox1 and Listbox2

I have a code that populates Listbox1 with workbooks from a folder. Clicking on any workbook will display all relevant sheets in Listbox2.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

Dim idx As Long, sName As String
Dim bk As Workbook, sh As Worksheet

idx = ListBox1.ListIndex
sName = ListBox1.List(idx)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set bk = Workbooks.Open("D:\Counts\" & sName)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
For Each sh In bk.Worksheets
    ListBox2.AddItem sh.Name
Next
bk.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub

'====================================

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

   Dim DIRECTORY As String
   'Clear Listboxes
   ListBox1.Clear

   'list directories
   DIRECTORY = Dir("D:\Counts\*.xls", vbNormal)
   Do Until DIRECTORY = ""
        'add filename to listbox
       ListBox1.AddItem DIRECTORY
       DIRECTORY = Dir()
   Loop

End Sub
```

**Problem** -

The code keeps adding sheets to Listbox2

**Requirement** -

I want the code to display sheets of selected workbook one at a time.

So, if I click on first workbook, the code should display sheets relevant to first workbook. If I click on second workbook, the code should display sheets relevant to second workbook only, so on and so forth.

What part of the code should be changed to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a

```
ListBox2.Clear
```

In your ListBox1_Click() sub before the for each statement

Comment: thanks for that bit of code. It works. How do I close this post